# using Omit to remove nested prop in typescript interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component in a library that is typed like this:

```js
export interface LogoBoxProps {
  img: React.ReactElement<HTMLImageElement>,
  srText?: string,
  href?: LinkProps['href']
}

export type LogoBoxType = React.FC<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & LogoBoxProps>

export const LogoBox: LogoBoxType = () => ...;
```

Now when I use this from the library in a project, I would like to write a component that uses this component as basis but in the rest of the project, it uses the other one:

```js
import {LogoBox as LogoBoxBase, LogoBoxProps as LogoBoxPropsBase, LogoBoxType as LogoBoxTypeBase} from "@lc/ui";

export const LogoBox = ({
  className,
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return <LogoBoxBase img={<img className="navigation__logo" src="assets/img/logo_small.svg" alt="Logo of the thing" />}>
    {children && <h1>{children}</h1>}
  </LogoBoxBase>;
};
```

But I am having issues with the typing. If I set `LogoBox: LogoBoxTypeBase`, any usage of the `<LogoBox>` Component in the project (not in the library), will prompt me that `img` is missing.

Basically, what I want is: `LogoBox: Omit<LogoBoxTypeBase, Omit<LogoBoxPropsBase, 'img'>>`, but that doesn't work. I also tried `LogoBox: Omit<LogoBoxTypeBase, 'img'>`, but that also does not work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to combine types with interfaces.
LogoBoxType could be converted to an interface.